# Calculating unused IP in excel

Tags: excel, vba, networking

I'm keeping a spreadsheet of all my IP addresses on my home network.  I have set out a scope of 50 addresses for static configuration and from those I've defined a few "groups" for certain types of devices like computers or media players NAS etc.  Because of this I have unused addresses in between others which leads me to my actual question.  How to I write a formula in excel that determines the available addresses and also I'd like it to calculate the next and third available address as well, which I'd delimit by a decimal like 1 or 2 or 3

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this in a few very creative ways, im not very good with formulas but if vba is ok i can do that.

```
Public Sub GetIPs()

Dim RngArr As Variant
Dim IPRange(0 To 255) As Boolean    'you may want to change this to account for reserved IPs
Dim Rw As Long
Dim Results As Worksheet

RngArr = Sheet1.UsedRange.Columns("A:C").Value

If Not IsArray(RngArr) Then Exit Sub    'make sure we have more than 1 cell of data

For Rw = LBound(RngArr, 1) To UBound(RngArr, 1)
    If RngArr(Rw, 2) Like "*.*.*.*" Then 'Just a very simple wilcard search for an IP
        IPRange(CByte(Split(RngArr(Rw, 2), ".")(3))) = True 'set IPRange to true on the index/IP number
    End If
Next Rw

Set Results = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add

For Rw = LBound(IPRange, 1) To UBound(IPRange, 1)
    Results.Cells(1 + Rw, 1).Value = "192.168.1." & Rw
    If IPRange(Rw) = True Then
        Results.Cells(1 + Rw, 2).Value = "Taken"
    Else
        Results.Cells(1 + Rw, 2).Value = "Available"
    End If
Next Rw
End Sub
```

This assumes your sheet is (CodeName) Sheet1 (this is the name it has in the VBA Properties window) change as required.
It also Assumes your IP data is in columns B
it will create a new sheet with a list of all taken and available IP addresses, just edit as needed.

Comment: This is kind of what I was looking at, if this could work in a way that I could have the first second and third available IP I'd be perfect.  I tried to use it with a vlookup and if statement (separately and together as one formula) but I couldn't get an argument that stated first, second or third

Comment: well if you wanted to use this method you could either just loop down the Taken/Available column and list the available IP's, or just modify the original code to (the last loop) to ignore Taken IPS and list the Available ones instead

Answer (score 0):

I created some IP (both IPv4 and IPv6) routines for Excel. I have one, `SubnetIPv4(IPv4 As String, Bits As Integer, Offset As Long) As String`:

***Warning: I created these as quick-and-dirty solutions, and I haven't used them for several years.***

This is a common function for the other functions:

```
Function CountStr(Source As String, Target As String) As Integer
    Dim c, i As Integer
    c = 0
    If Not ((Source = "") Or (Target = "")) Then
        For i = 1 To Len(Source)
            If Mid(Source, i, Len(Target)) = Target Then
                c = c + 1
            End If
        Next
    End If
    CountStr = c
End Function
```

**IPv4:**

Notes:

1. Macros must be enabled
2. IPv4 is a string representing an IPv4 address in dotted decimal
   format
3. Bits is an integer (0 to 32) representing the number of mask bits
4. Offset is an integer representing the host address offset into the
   subnet
5. Using Offset `0` will return a subnet for any IP address
6. Using an IPv4 address of `255.255.255.255` and Offset `0` will return a mask of Bits
   size

This function will determine if the string is an IPv4 address:

```
Function IsIPv4(IPv4 As String) As Boolean
    Dim s As String
    On Error GoTo InvalidIPv4
    s = SubnetIPv4(IPv4, 32, 0)
    IsIPv4 = True
    Exit Function
InvalidIPv4:
    IsIPv4 = False
End Function
```

This function will return an IPv4 address:

```
Function SubnetIPv4(IPv4 As String, Bits As Integer, Offset As Long) As String
    Dim a() As String
    Dim c, d, i As Integer
    Dim m As Long
    Dim s As String
    If IPv4 = "" Then
        GoTo InvalidIPv4
    End If
    c = CountStr(IPv4, ".")
    If c <> 3 Then
        GoTo InvalidIPv4
    End If
    c = CountStr(IPv4, "..")
    If c > 1 Then
        GoTo InvalidIPv4
    End If
    If (Left(IPv4, 1) = ".") Or (Right(IPv4, 1) = ".") Then
        GoTo InvalidIPv4
    End If
    a = Split(IPv4, ".")
    If UBound(a) <> 3 Then
        GoTo InvalidIPv4
    End If
    On Error GoTo InvalidIPv4
    For i = 0 To 3
        If (Len(a(i)) > 0) And (Len(a(i)) < 4) Then
            a(i) = CInt(a(i))
            If (a(i) < 0) Or (a(i) > 255) Then
                GoTo InvalidIPv4
            End If
        Else
            GoTo InvalidIPv4
        End If
    Next
    If (Bits < 0) Or (Bits > 32) Then
        GoTo InvalidIPv4
    End If
    c = Bits Mod 8
    d = Bits \ 8
    If (Bits <> 0) And (c = 0) Then
        c = 8
        d = d - 1
    End If
    m = 0
    For i = 0 To 7
        m = m * 2
        If c > 0 Then
            m = m + 1
            c = c - 1
        End If
    Next
    a(d) = CStr(CLng(a(d)) And m)
    For i = d + 1 To 3
        a(i) = "0"
    Next
    If Offset < 0 Then
        GoTo InvalidIPv4
    End If
    m = 0
    For i = 1 To (32 - Bits)
        m = m * 2
        m = m + 1
    Next
    If Offset > m Then
        GoTo InvalidIPv4
    End If
    m = Offset
    For i = 3 To 0 Step -1
        a(i) = a(i) + (m Mod 256)
        m = m \ 256
    Next
    s = ""
    For i = 0 To 3
        s = s + CStr(a(i)) + "."
    Next
    s = Left(s, Len(s) - 1)
    SubnetIPv4 = s
    Exit Function
InvalidIPv4:
    Error (3)
End Function
```

**IPv6:**

Notes:

1. Macros must be enabled
2. IPv6 is a string representing an IPv6 address in standard format
   (leading 0s are optional and `::` works)
3. Bits is an integer (0 to 128) representing the number of mask bits
4. Offset is a string representing the host address offset into the
   subnet in standard format (leading 0s are optional and `::` works)
5. Using Offset equivalent to `0` (`::`, `::0`, `0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0`, etc.) will
   return a subnet for any IP address
6. Using an IPv6 address of `FFFF:FFFF:FFFF:FFFF:FFFF:FFFF:FFFF:FFFF` and Offset
   equivalent to 0 will return a mask of Bits size

This function will determine if the string is an IPv6 address:

```
Function IsIPv6(IPv6 As String) As Boolean
    Dim s As String
    On Error GoTo InvalidIPv6
    s = SubnetIPv6(IPv6, 128, "::")
    IsIPv6 = True
    Exit Function
InvalidIPv6:
    IsIPv6 = False
End Function
```

This function will return an IPv6 address:

```
Function SubnetIPv6(IPv6 As String, Bits As Integer, Offset As String) As String
    Dim a() As String
    Dim c, d, i As Integer
    Dim m As Long
    Dim s, t As String
    If IPv6 = "" Then
        GoTo InvalidIPv6
    End If
    c = CountStr(IPv6, ":")
    If (c < 2) Or (c > 8) Then
        GoTo InvalidIPv6
    End If
    d = CountStr(IPv6, "::")
    If d > 1 Then
        GoTo InvalidIPv6
    End If
    If (Left(IPv6, 1) = ":") And (Not (Left(IPv6, 2) = "::")) Then
        GoTo InvalidIPv6
    End If
    If (Right(IPv6, 1) = ":") And (Not (Right(IPv6, 2) = "::")) Then
        GoTo InvalidIPv6
    End If
    s = IPv6
    If d = 1 Then
        If Left(s, 2) = "::" Then
            s = "0" + s
        End If
        If Right(s, 2) = "::" Then
            s = s + "0"
        End If
        t = ":"
        For i = c To 7
            t = t + "0:"
        Next
        s = Replace(s, "::", t)
    End If
    a = Split(s, ":")
    If UBound(a) <> 7 Then
        GoTo InvalidIPv6
    End If
    On Error GoTo InvalidIPv6
    For i = 0 To 7
        If (Len(a(i)) > 0) And (Len(a(i)) < 5) Then
            a(i) = WorksheetFunction.Hex2Dec(a(i))
        Else
            GoTo InvalidIPv6
        End If
    Next
    If (Bits < 0) Or (Bits > 128) Then
        GoTo InvalidIPv6
    End If
    c = Bits Mod 16
    d = Bits \ 16
    If (Bits <> 0) And (c = 0) Then
        c = 16
        d = d - 1
    End If
    m = 0
    For i = 0 To 15
        m = m * 2
        If c > 0 Then
          m = m + 1
          c = c - 1
        End If
    Next
    a(d) = CStr(CLng(a(d)) And m)
    For i = d + 1 To 7
        a(i) = "0"
    Next
    If Offset = "" Then
        GoTo InvalidIPv6
    End If
    c = CountStr(Offset, ":")
    If (c < 2) Or (c > 8) Then
        GoTo InvalidIPv6
    End If
    d = CountStr(Offset, "::")
    If d > 1 Then
        GoTo InvalidIPv6
    End If
    If (Left(Offset, 1) = ":") And (Not (Left(Offset, 2) = "::")) Then
        GoTo InvalidIPv6
    End If
    If (Right(Offset, 1) = ":") And (Not (Right(Offset, 2) = "::")) Then
        GoTo InvalidIPv6
    End If
    s = Offset
    If d = 1 Then
        If Left(s, 2) = "::" Then
            s = "0" + s
        End If
        If Right(s, 2) = "::" Then
            s = s + "0"
        End If
        t = ":"
        For i = c To 7
            t = t + "0:"
        Next
        s = Replace(s, "::", t)
    End If
    b = Split(s, ":")
    If UBound(b) <> 7 Then
        GoTo InvalidIPv6
    End If
    On Error GoTo InvalidIPv6
    For i = 0 To 7
        If (Len(b(i)) > 0) And (Len(b(i)) < 5) Then
            b(i) = WorksheetFunction.Hex2Dec(b(i))
        Else
            GoTo InvalidIPv6
        End If
    Next
    c = Bits Mod 16
    d = Bits \ 16
    If (Bits <> 0) And (c = 0) Then
        c = 16
        d = d - 1
    End If
    m = 0
    For i = 0 To 15
        m = m * 2
        If c > 0 Then
          m = m + 1
          c = c - 1
        End If
    Next
    For i = 0 To d - 1
        If b(i) <> "0" Then
            GoTo InvalidIPv6
        End If
    Next
    If b(d) <> CStr(CLng(b(d)) And m) Then
        GoTo InvalidIPv6
    End If
    For i = 7 To d Step -1
        a(i) = CStr(CLng(a(i)) + CLng(b(i)))
    Next
    s = ""
    For i = 0 To 7
        s = s + WorksheetFunction.Dec2Hex(a(i)) + ":"
    Next
    s = Left(s, Len(s) - 1)
    SubnetIPv6 = s
    Exit Function
InvalidIPv6:
    Error (3)
End Function
```